# Find a misplaced folder in Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

In Outlook 2013, how do I find a missing/misplaced folder? All I know is the name of the folder, nothing else. Please do not ask me to go to Tools. I have no such tab. Please do not suggest looking for an email in the folder, as I do not remember anything about the emails in the folder.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the root of the mailbox > Click Properties > Click Folder size... button and then you can browse all folders under root mailbox folder, recursively. It will show the full path of the folders, you can easily find the accidentally moved folder and browse to it.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @WasifHasan, Folder size could help you find folders or subfolders like below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have a Search button - All recent Outlook have a Search facility.

Click on the Search and then possibly Advanced.  Make sure you set Search for ALL folders including Archives.

Enter your folder name and it should come up.